# How to write logs in SQCLR procedure to Elastic?

Tags: sql-server, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, sqlclr

Is it possible to write logs in SQLCLR procedure to ElasticSearch (EFK or ELK stacks)?
If it is where are any examples?

Comment: What type of logs do you want to write, or rather where do the logs originate from? I would strongly suggest you write to Elastic from where the logs originate, (unless the logs are SQL Server, in which case I wonder why you would like to store them in Elastic). I am a big proponent of SQLCLR, but if you can do whatever you want to do from outside of SQL Server, you should do so.

Comment: Yes, it is right. First of all it is interesting how to ;-). My situation: I have multiple clients and one database. I'd like to add to SQLCLR functions to send logs to ELK, EFK stack. I have already made SQLCLR proc which writes to GrayLog. It uses pure c# classes. Btw, I have used your article about how to add SQLCLR fun and avoid db trustworthy. Thank you.